# how to label in between surveyjs radio group

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

[image]

But using surveyjs i cannot find any solution to add between the radio button.

some working code to edit [link](https://jsfiddle.net/myselfdesai/xeyqca75/)[2](https://jsfiddle.net/myselfdesai/xeyqca75/)

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWQVL.png
  [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/myselfdesai/xeyqca75/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding the you are trying to add the sub title between your single group of radio button.

For this you have to manually add the custom java-script code manipulate DOM element. The functionality provided by surveyjs is given below.

```
survey
    .onAfterRenderQuestion
    .add(function(){
     <add your custom javascript code>
     });
```

I have added the code with considering basic DOM element position.

```
survey
    .onAfterRenderQuestion
    .add(function(){
        $( 
        //first I have collected all the div element position of using question form id 
        let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#question_id form div");
        $('</br></br><span><h4> Medical/Dental</h4><span>').insertBefore(divs[0]);
        $('</br></br><span><h4> Nursing </h4></span>').insertBefore(divs[9]);

    });
```

This can solve your problem remember to add proper div object index to add span for particular location.